# My TextView Doesn't Seen

Tags: java, android

I want to see on the screen a `Button`  object, a `TextView` object and a `MyView` object. But only appear `Button` object and `MyVıew` object. I think , MyView overlapping(above the `TextView`) with TextView. Because If I don't add(`b.addView(a);`)`MyView` object to my layout, `Button` and `TextView` objects appear on the screen. But If I add(`b.addView(a);`) MyView , TextView is gone. How can I solve this problem?

MyView.java file:

```
package com.example.mehmet.catchtheball;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("lightGray"));
        canvas.drawCircle(500, 500, 150, paint);
    }
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

`Customer.java` file :

```
package com.example.mehmet.catchtheball;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class Customer extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer);

        MyView a = new MyView(this);
        RelativeLayout b = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        b.addView(a); // If I do this , TextView gone.

        final TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        label.setText("HelloEveryOne"); // My TextView

        a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`activity_customer.xml` file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mehmet.catchtheball.main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="undo"
        android:text="@string/undo" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a LinearLayout as container below textView3 and add all to then

Comment: The RelativeLayout by default will place all Views on top of each other

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos How should I add as container, I don't understand, I am sorry.

Comment: In the XML here you posted, add a <LinearLayout> with layout_belowOf=textView3, at your code where you do b.addView(a) replace with: LinearLayout c = findViewById(R.id.ll_c_container) and c.addView(a)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Thanks a lot, the problem solved, but Is there way do the TextView above the RelativeLayout? Or Is there a way without using LinearLayout?

Comment: If you want to all components to be in an linear axis you can have just one linearlayout (all addViews will add below the last view)

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this activity_customer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mehmet.catchtheball.main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="undo"
        android:text="@string/undo" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Y are you increasing the layout hierarchy. This is a terrible idea

Comment: That will depend on what later want to do with the layout. Maybe there is a better solution but I don't think that current solution it's a big problem.

Comment: A good programmer looks both ways before crossing a one-way street.

Comment: A good programmer knows that only need to look one way before crossing to one-way street. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinearLayout as container below textView3 and add all to then

In the XML here you posted, add a  with layout_belowOf=textView3, at your code where you do b.addView(a) replace with: LinearLayout c = findViewById(R.id.ll_c_container) and c.addView(a)

If you want to all components to be in an linear axis you can have just one linearlayout (all addViews will add below the last view)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="undo"
            android:text="@string/undo" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In your java class just do this one (Sorry i am writing kotlin code

```
MyView a = new MyView(this);
        val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView3.id)
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
    relativeLayout.addView(textView, params)
```

Comment: you can also use relative layout but you need to add rule. Easiest way is using Linear Layout. The Code which i have shown you is the minimal hierarchy code.